# sql query order output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table called `Property` and the data is like

```
   pid     city           state          state_abb      address1   address2
    x1     NewCity        NHANy              NH          xxxx      gfg
    x2     Gloucester     Manchestar         MA          newAde    xxxx
    x3     OtherC         NewYork            NY          yyyy
```

I want a query with search keyword to display order like (state or state_abb), city, address1, adress2

For ex:

If I search keyword with **New** The result output should

```
    pid   city         state        state_abb   address1    address2
     x3   OtherC       NewYork         NY       yyyy 
     x1   NewCity      NHANy           NH       xxxx        gfg
     x2   Gloucester   Manchester      MA       newAde      xxxx
```

I don't want unmatched rows.I want display only matched rows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? Please post the queries you attempted and explain where you are having problems.

Comment: @Oded Agreed, I don't want to type the whole query, but am willing to help...

Comment: Thank you for your reply i am poor in sql so plz Give me some idea i can try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It think the question is how to order the results, not how to perform the search.   Try this as your ORDER BY clause

```
order by
 case when charindex('NEW',state) >0 then 1000 else 0 end desc,
 case when charindex('NEW',city) >0 then 100 else 0 end desc, 
 case when charindex('NEW',address) >0 then 10 else 0 end desc
```

Where clause to only get matching rows

```
 select * from Property where
        city     like '%New%' or
        state    like '%New%' or
        address1 like '%New%' or
        address2 like '%New%'
```

Comment: Can u tell me the query i dont want unmatched data rows

Comment: If you don't want unmatched rows, you need a where clause like Jim Garrisson suggested below.   I'll add it to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT pid, city, state, stat_abb, address1, address2
from property
where city like '%New%'
OR state like '%New%'
OR address1 like '%New%'
```

Comment: of course, searching on several fields with `OR` and also using `LIKE` with a leading `%` will completely and utterly avoid any possible indices to be used, and thus performance will be horribly slow....

Comment: @marc_s agreed but with the info he provided it gives him a startng point

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
select * from Property where
    city     like '%New%' or
    state    like '%New%' or
    address1 like '%New%' or
    address2 like '%New%'
```

I assume you don't want to look at the `pid` column.

Comment: of course, searching on several fields with `OR` and also using `LIKE` with a leading `%` will completely and utterly avoid any possible indices to be used, and thus performance will be horribly slow....

Comment: @marc_s agreed, but the OP hasn't given much context.  This could be perfectly usable if the table size isn't large

Comment: indeed - just wanted to point out that this approach is not be the best to scale to large numbers of rows .... for small numbers, it's irrelevant

Comment: "Its not working" is not enough information.  What do you mean?

Comment: Its giving same table output not getting order

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from Property 
order by case
           when state     like 'New%' then 1
           when state_abb like 'New%' then 1
           when city      like 'New%' then 2
           when address1  like 'New%' then 3
           when address2  like 'New%' then 4
         end
```